# Use SF Symbols system image for static UIApplicationShortcutItem

Tags: ios, ios13, uiapplicationshortcutitem, sf-symbols

When specifying home screen quick actions, `UIApplicationShortcutItems`, in your Info.plist, is there a way to use a system image from SF Symbols?

The [docs noting the available iOS keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW36) doesn't specify a key to do this, besides specifying one of the predefined enum cases from `UIApplicationShortcutItemIconType` such as `UIApplicationShortcutIconTypeSearch`.

It is possible to use a system image when creating dynamic quick actions via a new initializer `UIApplicationShortcutIcon.init(systemImageName: String)`. Is there a Info.plist key that allows this for static quick actions?

Comment: You could try to get the stock application into your computer, either by extracting them from the `ipsw` update file or with a jailbroken device, and explore their `Info.plist` files to see if any of them are using SF Symbols.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `UIApplicationShortcutItemIconSymbolName` instead of `UIApplicationShortcutItemIconFile` in your Info.plist.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere? Hesitant to use it.

Comment: It's documented here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/menus_and_shortcuts/add_home_screen_quick_actions

Answer (score 17):

#### Native but NOT a much compatible way: (read to the end)

There is a [poor documented way](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/menus_and_shortcuts/add_home_screen_quick_actions#3701682) and that is to use `UIApplicationShortcutItemIconSymbolName` instead of `UIApplicationShortcutItemIconFile` in the `Info.plist` file.

---

#### Old but may better way:

Since there are not too many symbols that you need to use statically at the same time, here is the solution:

1. Select the symbol you need and export it from **SF Symbols.app**:

[image: Exporting]

2. Import it in the **Assets.xcassets**:

[image: Assets]

3. Use its name for the key `UIApplicationShortcutItemIconFile`:

[image: Info.plist]

## Result

[image: Result]

---

## Conclusion

The second method also brings **more benefits** to your app:

- Backward compatibility (supporting iOS 12 and below)
- Forward compatibility! (preventing from breaking changes)
- Wider support

More description **[here in these answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67946409/5623035)**

Comment: Besides the manual effort, the only concern I'd add is that Apple may change (or modify) the images in the future. Depending on the image, this would be very good or very bad, but worth considering before you do this.

Answer (score 2):

I read the docs and tried several methods to get this working but the conclusion I reached is that this won't be possible for two main reasons:

- SF Symbols are only available for native use on devices running iOS 13 or older.
- `Info.plist` file can specify a `platform` and `device` type but you can't specify an OS version.

In Apple's [documents](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sf-symbols/overview/) it's also stated that:

> You can use SF Symbols in apps running in iOS 13 and later, watchOS 6 and later, and tvOS 13 and later. To browse the full set of symbols, download the SF Symbols app.

This means that you are able to use these symbols but with a standard way. Here is what you can do:

- Download the SF Symbols app from [here](https://developer.apple.com/design/resources/).
- Export the symbols you'd like to use as SVG files.
- Add exported SVG files to your assets.
- Use the asset name for the value of `UIApplicationShortcutItemIconFile` key.

This may not be the method you'd have hoped but it's a valid solution for using SF Symbols as shortcut icons so I hope this works for you.