# Check if image is available for Image(systemName: ) initializer

Tags: swift, image, swiftui

Is there a way to check if proposed `systemName` has a corresponding image which is going to be rendered properly? This is necessary to display a placeholder image in case when the system doesn't contain the image in question.

Comment: Testing, either the hardcoded string will match an image or it won't. This will never change during runtime so once it works it will work. If you need to support older versions where the image (or functionality like multi colouring) doesn't exist then you need to manually import them to your assets folder. See for instance [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62731361/9223839)

Comment: Yes, that's how it usually goes. Although I can imagine situations when `systemName` or `name` parameters can go out of sync with assets on device. This is the reason why UI/NSImage initialisers are [failable](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=17). Looks like is not possible to have failable inits for view structs inside @viewbuilder, but maybe there is an option to test against receiving an `EmptyView` (just an idea).

Comment: Again, if the asset folder content goes out of sync with the string names used this should be discovered during testing since it’s very very unlikely it happens when the app has been released.

Comment: Totally agree, @Joakim. But right now I find it convenient (just for the particular rapid development case) to fall-through from systemName to asset name and to the placeholder systemName in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer not to couple UIImage with SwiftUI, when possible. So I use a tuple and let the invoker specify whether it comes from SF Symbols or is a local asset. Something like a property in your SwiftUI struct:

```
var icon: (name: String, isSystem: Bool)
```

Then in the view body you can check `isSystem`:

```
var body: some View {
  if icon.isSystem {
    Image(systemName: icon.name)
  } else {
    Image(icon.name)
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As quick way get a "placeholdered" `Image` I made up a small extension:

```
extension Image {
#if os(iOS)
    typealias PlatformImage = UIImage
#elseif os(macOS)
    typealias PlatformImage = NSImage
#endif
    init(for name: String, placeholder: String = "placeholdertext.fill") {
        if let uiImage = PlatformImage(systemName: name) {
            self = Image(uiImage: uiImage)
        } else if let uiImage = PlatformImage(named: name){
            self = Image(uiImage: uiImage)
        } else {
            self = Image(systemName: placeholder)
        }
    }
}
```

This way looks a bit overengineered. I would prefer to test for an `EmptyView` or something like that. But it does it's job.

Comment: This code only compiles under iOS. Lots of errors if you choose a macOS (AppKit) target.